# Create regular expression in ruby on rails for validate username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need create a regular expression in ruby on rails for validate the user name following this rules:

```
 1)- The user name accept only lowercase letters, numbers,dashes and underscores
 2)- The first character must be a lowercase letter
 3)- The username have as minimum 6 characters and 30 characters as maximun
```

I thought some like this, but I'm not very sure

```
  /^ ([a-z][a-z\_-0-9]+){6,30}  $/
```

Comment: `/^[a-z][a-z\-0-9_]{5,29}$/` seems like it would work.

Comment: I am wrong. The spaces are not accepted

Comment: Madbreaks  can I change 0-9 for \d?    and  a-z for some other class

Comment: Sure. check the docs on character classes.

Comment: I worked perfect. very grateful to you Madbreaks

Comment: @Madbreaks, to complete this question, I suggest you post your comment as an answer, which daniel can accept if he chooses to do so. You and daniel might also consider deleting the comments.

Comment: Thanks the Tim Man. This is a scholar proyect in Spanish. I'd like to know your code. I am in the dude if the first character should be a letter. Can an user name accept letter uppercase or begin it with a number. Some know if exists a international patron for the username

Comment: Madbreaks Can you post your answer?

Comment: /^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/ I find this regular expression on internet

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, was just kind of in a hurry. ;) Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
/^[a-z][a-z\-0-9_]{5,29}$/
```

I'll break it down:

- `^[a-z]` - the sequence starts with (`^`) a lowercase character
- `[a-z\-0-9_]` - any of the chars in that group
- `{5,29}` - between 5 and 29 (30 max, minus the one at the start of the sequence) of the previous set of chars
- `$` the end of the sequence

You mentioned character classes - sure, you can use them.  I typically don't because they're not as portable (someone may chime in and prove me wrong here) and I don't think they're as easy to understand, simply because I tend to forget which ones are which. YMMV